# SSL Pinning vs Certificate Transparency

Tags: ssl, certificate-pinning, certificate-transparency

I am trying to understand whether SSL Pinning or Certificate transparency is the right way to go. Been reading online and found some article that suggests the SSL Pinning is depreciated. Can you help me with some insights about that? what is better? is any PK pinning or certificate pinning actually depreciated?

Thank you

E.M.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/